# Connect to MSSQL server using ODBC

Tags: c, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, odbc

I never used ODBC until today neither MSSQL.
I have a MSSQL server running on 89.12.12.12 (example). I want to connect to it using C.

Right now I managed to put the following code:

```
SQLRETURN ret;
    SQLHENV henv;
    SQLHDBC hdbc;

    ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &henv);
    if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {

        ret = SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER *)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
        if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
            ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc);

            if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
                SQLSetConnectAttr(hdbc, SQL_LOGIN_TIMEOUT, (SQLPOINTER)5, 0);

                ret = SQLConnect(hdbc, (SQLCHAR*) "89.12.12.12", SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*) "root", 5, (SQLCHAR*) "t00r", 9);
                if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {

                    MessageBoxA(0, "Connect ok", NULL, 0);
                }
                else MessageBoxA(0, "Connect failed!", NULL, 0);


            }
        }
```

However no connection is made, where I can specify IP address. Thanks!

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: Dont ignore errors, e.g. call SQLGetDiagRec for error information after SQLConnect - assuming it even gets that far.

Comment: it gets that far, my question is how to specify ip!

Answer (score 0):

I want to help you. But I do not know where to specify remote IP address.
I set my ODBC DSN in my localhost server. and I just specified DSN name like this.

```
ret = SQLConnect(hdbc, (SQLCHAR*) "ODBC DSN name", SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*) "root", 5, (SQLCHAR*) "t00r", 9);
            if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {

                MessageBoxA(0, "Connect ok", NULL, 0);
            }
            else MessageBoxA(0, "Connect failed!", NULL, 0);
```

So, I suggest you sfecify IP like this. (I did not test it!)

```
ret = SQLConnect(hdbc, (SQLCHAR*) "ipaddress/ODBC DSN name", SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*) "root", 5, (SQLCHAR*) "t00r", 9);
            if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {

                MessageBoxA(0, "Connect ok", NULL, 0);
            }
            else MessageBoxA(0, "Connect failed!", NULL, 0);
```